# No overload matches this call. Erro componente React

Tags: react, typescript

Eae pessoal, estou com o seguinte problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A interface q estou usando:

```
export interface ToastMessage {
  id: string;
  type?: 'success' | 'error' | 'info';
  title: string;
  description?: string;
}
```

e onde uso o componente (Container) passando os parâmetros está dando esse erro ai do print

```
return (
    <Container type={message.type} hasDescription={!!message.description}>
      {icons[message.type || 'info']}

      <div>
        <strong>{message.title}</strong>
        {message.description && <p>{message.description}</p>}
      </div>

      <button onClick={() => removeToast(message.id)} type="button">
        <FiXCircle size={18} />
      </button>
    </Container>
  );
```

Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Answer (score -1):

A tipagem do `message.type` está diferente da tipagem da prop type do seu componente, o que você pode fazer é adicionar uma tipagem igual da prop type

Ex:

```js
type exemplo = 'success' | 'error' | 'info';
<Container type={message.type as exemplo} hasDescription={!!message.description}>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).